# Compute integral $\int_0^a{f'(x)\cdot f(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

what is the integral of the following function:
$\int_0^a{f'(x)\cdot f(x)}dx$

Not quite sure how to integrate it.

Comment: Which integration methods do you know?

Comment: It's good to give us context, so that we can tailor our answer to your level. If you tell us what you've tried, that helps us answer better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $u = f(x)$ as a substitution  and $du = f'(x)dx$ the integral becomes

$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(a)} u du = \frac{u^2}{2}]^{f(a)}_{f(0)} = \frac{f(a)^2-f(0)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $2 f'(x) f(x)$ is what you get when you differentiate $f(x)^2$.

Comment: I am not sure how to handle the product of both... is it like a reverse product rule?

Comment: @Maria Don't use any rules. Just use the definition of integration as "the reverse of differentiation".

Comment: Someone seems unsure about whether or not to downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative hint: if you integrate by parts, you obtain

$$\int_0^a f'(x)f(x)\,dx = -\int_0^af(x)f'(x)\,dx + \left[f(x)f(x) \right]_0^a $$

Comment: Since I only have basic integration knowledge, integration by parts is new to me and I don't really understand how it works :( can you maybe explain a bit more?

Comment: I have used the integration by parts formula (which follows from the derivative of the product)

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g'(x)h(x)dx =-\int_{x_1}^{x_2}g(x)h'(x)dx+\left[g(x)h(x)\right]_{x_1}^{x_2} $$

for an appropriate choice of $h,g,x_1$ and $x_2$.  You should be able to obtain the integral you want form the formula I've written in the answer.